# Send data(String ) from Vuejs to SpringBoot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, vue.js, http, vuejs3

I want to send string from my vue js project to my backend SpringBoot, But the problem I receive value Null not the value send.
Code in vue js

> ```
> sendString() {
>   axios.post('/apii/send-string', {
>     myString: this.myString
>   })
>   .then(response => {
>     console.log(response.data)
>   })
>   .catch(error => {
>     console.log(error)
>   })
> },
> ```

And code in my SpringBoot

> ```
>     @PostMapping("/send-string")
> public ResponseEntity<String> receiveString(@RequestBody String myString) {
>     System.out.println("Le message recu : " + myString);
>     return ResponseEntity.ok("String reçu avec succès !");
> }
> ```

The result of

```
   System.out.println("Le message recu : " + myString);
```

Is :

```
Le message recu : null
```

In my navigator I have at http://localhost:8080/apii/send-string this display :

```
"errordate":"2023-03-22T11:05:46.95864527","fishtag":"no_fishtag","url":"/apii/send-string","httpcode":405,"messages":[{"level":"ERROR","message":"GET method is not supported for this request. Supported methods are: POST ","code":"DEFAULT"}]}
```

And in the console of the browser I have :

`GET http://localhost:8080/apii/send-string 405`

If anyone knows how to send String to SpringBoot? Or What is the wrong in my code?

Comment: This is possibly a problem between ajax call and backend, and has nothing to do with Vue. Check the Network Tab in the Browser Dev Tools, to see if data was sent correctly and use Postman/Insomnia to test the backend API.

Comment: I have this error in the console of browser :   GET http://localhost:8080/apii/send-string 405.

Comment: You should check the browser network tab while calling `sendString()`. Since your API is defined for POST requests, it makes  no sense to open the URL in browser, which does a GET request. Use Postman/Insomnia or some other tool to simulate a POST request.

Comment: In browser network i have Status code 200 don't have problem                                             Request URL: http://localhost:8080/apii/send-string
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: Status 200 is not enough. Check the request data, if the `myString` was really filled. If yes, then you should check your backend. If no, then check the frontend.

Comment: Okay i think that I don't now where i can find this information ? in payload a have my message but response a have null